# VBA Text Form Field calculator

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to create three text form fields in MS WORD, where, when you enter the two integers, in these two forms, the third form sums them. Sorry for my bad english. I added an image, so you could understand me more

http://tinypic.com/r/29lcp00/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to create a table:(example)
[image: Table Example]

in the cell to the right of "Sum" click in it then in the tool ribbon above go to Layout(Under table tools) click on formula and enter =SUM(ABOVE) and set number format "0". This will get you the sum of integers in the cells above within that column.

**For more detailed instructions:**

[MS Article "Use a formula in a Word table"](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Use-a-formula-in-a-Word-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN)

Comment: Can you add more information on what exactly you need then? Your question is a bit obscure.

Comment: I need to create a form with ms word, where you input 2 numbers, and they are summed together, and i need to create sum function with VBA. The form i can create in developer tab.

Comment: Are you wanting this form created by hand or through some other script? If you're simply wanting the form itself to have two fields containing numbers and a third field containing the sum of the first two fields, solution above using "=SUM(ABOVE)" is a VBA function. Are you talking about VB? (Visual basic) vs (Visual basic for applications)